# How to pass the first column of a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have just written this code:

```
   EXl = ('C:\\vd36e404.vdb','C:\\vd368c03.vdb')
   x=0 
   for x in EXl:
      import os   
      filesize= os.path.getsize(x)
      print (filesize);
```

What I would like to do is this. I have a csv file which has in the first column the list of path I need to give to the above program, which should then give me as output the size of the path-file given by the csv file.

Does anyone know how to code that?

Comment: read about the csv reader: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html. With your code as it is now EXl is a tuple. EXl[0] is the first filename... Play around, you'll solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this would fit you :

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Look at this example :

```
import csv
spamReader = csv.reader(open('eggs.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in spamReader:
    print ', '.join(row)

Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```